# How to send jmeter performace testing result to developer?

Tags: jmeter

How to send graph, table result and tree result listener result to Project Manager or Developer?

Comment: Jmeter generates a file with extension .jmx. Is that happening in your case?

Comment: yes, it is. But Does project Manager or Developer need Jmeter to view that result?

Comment: the results are also displayed in the summary reports. have u enabled the summary reports?

Comment: No. you can save the .jmx file and can present it to the developer. jmeter is not required in that case

Comment: How to open .jmx file?

Comment: you need to export the result in an excel type format.

Comment: Is there any way to send or view results in Graph?? I mean we can view results as Jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Each of Listeners mentioned has configurable "Write results to file" section, you can save your test results to file and send them to whoever is interested. You can also configure [JMeter SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) to send results automatically at the end of test run
2. You can use combination of [JMeter Ant Task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/) which provides easy-readable HTML reports and screenshots of interesting graphs, all of them are embeddable into email message or Word or equivalent document.
3. There is a [free custom listener](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-analyze-load-test-results-using-new-blazemeter-listener) plugin which you can append to your test plan, it generates nice and professional-looking reports which you will be able to share as link.

Answer (score 0):

For Graph listener we have a data file creation option,before running the test script configure the data file what to be stored and in which format as CSV/XML...

For other listener we can store it as .jmx and sent to them.